# Loading a view from another controller and nib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a situation where a Panel is loaded with a view, but when a button is clicked I need to switch to a view that is in a different nib file, and that has a different controller.

So say I have Foo.nib, and Bar.nib.  Foo.nib is a panel and view, Bar.nib is just a view.  In FooController I have a line like:

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Foo" owner:self];
```

but I think I also need:

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Bar" owner:BarController];
```

And when the button is clicked I switch the View in FooController, but all of the BarController GUI elements are not handled by BarController.  Is this the right idea?  If so, I'm not able to get the Bar nib to load even though BarController is in the Foo nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to make 3 nib files: one for Panel, Foo and Bar. Then you can make FooController and BarController subclasses of NSViewController and create them like so

```
FooController *fooController = [[FooController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Foo" bundle:nil];
BarController *barController = [[BarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Bar" bundle:nil];
```

Whenever you need the view to be placed in the panel you would just do

```
NSView *fooView = [fooController view];
[panelView addSubview:fooView];
```

or you could swap the views using replaceSubview:with:

There's a more complete example [here](http://comelearncocoawithme.blogspot.com/2011/07/nsviewcontrollers.html)

Comment: Really appreciate that you included the tutorial as well.  Thanks a ton.